# Fitnesse: test ignored

Tags: fitnesse

When running a fitnesse test, I get see it is ignored (not run). I dont understand why. below is the code:

```
#!include .ActionDefinitions 
!path C:\Users\rdixit\Documents\Visual~3\Projects\LearningTestAutomation\LearningTestAutomation\bin\Debug\LearningTestAutomation.dll

|!SpecFlow.ActionIO|
|start browser| firefox| of version|36|
|navigate to url|https://csb-qaprod.cornerstoneondemand.com/learning|
|login|
```

Can you tell me why this page is ignored?

The root page is below:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}
#!define COMMAND_PATTERN {java -cp %p %m}
#!define TEST_RUNNER {fitlibrary.suite.FitLibraryServer}

!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\fitnesse\fitSharp\runner.exe}
#!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\fitnesse\dotnet\FolderRunner.exe}

!path C:/fitnesse/fitlibrary-2.0.jar
#!path ../bin
!path C:/fitnesse/fitnesse-standalone.jar
!path C:/fitnesse/lib/*.jar


!path C:/fitnesse/fitSharp/*.dll
!path C:/fitnesse/dotnet/*.dll

!path C:\Users\rdixit\Documents\Visual~3\Projects\LearningTestAutomation\LearningTestAutomation\bin\Debug\LearningTestAutomation.dll

!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
!define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}

!include .ActionDefinitions

|Import|
|SpecFlow.ActionIO|
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the error, when calling

|!SpecFlow.ActionIO|, I put ! inside the column. Its supposed to be:

!|SpecFlow.ActionIO|

works now.